# Access to main thread views from another thread

Tags: android

I thought that it is not possible to access main thread views in a new thread!

But why below codes runs without any problem?!

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            try {
                textView.append(InetAddress.getByName("192.168.1.252").getHostName() + "\n\n");
            } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }).start();
}
```

Comment: Are you sure? 
Clean your project , run it again and let us know about the result.

Comment: I've do that and steel works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it stands [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html#WorkerThreads):

> For example, below is some code for a click listener that downloads an
>   image from a separate thread and displays it in an ImageView:
>
> ```
> public void onClick(View v) {
>     new Thread(new Runnable() {
>         public void run() {
>             Bitmap b = loadImageFromNetwork("http://example.com/image.png");
>             mImageView.setImageBitmap(b);
>         }
>     }).start();
> }
> ```
>
> At first, this seems to work fine, because it creates a new thread to
>   handle the network operation. However, it violates the second rule of
>   the single-threaded model: do not access the Android UI toolkit from
>   outside the UI thread—this sample modifies the ImageView from the
>   worker thread instead of the UI thread. This can result in undefined
>   and unexpected behavior, which can be difficult and time-consuming to
>   track down.

So it works, but not recommended.
There are some recommended way to do this instead:

> To fix this problem, Android offers several ways to access the UI
>   thread from other threads. Here is a list of methods that can help:
>
> ```
> Activity.runOnUiThread(Runnable)
> View.post(Runnable)
> View.postDelayed(Runnable, long)
> ```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                try {
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            textView.append(InetAddress.getByName("192.168.1.252").getHostName() + "\n\n");
                        }
                    });                 
                } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }
```

runOnUiThread - is method from activity. if you work inside fragment you can call getActivity().runOnUiThread

Comment: That's not the answer to the question. The question was, why the code works.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to run the UI thread inside your new thread. 
Here is an example using anko.

```
btn_login.text = "LOGING IN"
doAsync {
   authenticate(email, password)
   uiThread { btn_login.text = "LOGIN" }
}
```